# How to provide permissions to edit a Page Manager Page?

Tags: 7, users

For our Drupal 7 site, I am tasked with creating a role for a non-developer end-user in our organization to manage a page we have that is provided by the Page Manager. By provided by, I mean that this page is not a node, and you can edit it by going to `/admin/structure/pages`.

I'm not really all that familiar with Panels and Page Manager, other than occasionally clicking through the UI to add something to a pane. I believe this is a panels page, but I am not sure.

Looking through the long list of permission, I see a lot of things that may or may not apply. At our organization, we have a policy to follow the least permissions necessary to do the job.

I would like to avoid trial and error as much as possible. How can I figure out which permissions an end-user would need simply to edit one page editable under `admin/structure/pages/edit/my_random_page`?